# using a mysql database using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, artisan-migrate

I'm trying to use a MySQL database using PHP and laravel, so far I have created the database in phpmyadmin called "laravel", i have updated my .env file to the following:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

but when I run "php artisan migrate" in the terminal, I get the following error:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to create the database yourself, as the user that Laravel uses normally should not have that kind of access (at least, in production). Once you create the database, then Laravel can use it.

Comment: yes sorry my mistake I have created it and now I'm trying to use it

Comment: which's laravel version you used it?

Comment: I am using 8.10.1

Comment: So after creating the database, is the issue resolved or changed?

Comment: I get the above error after I created the database on phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

after modifying the .env file, you have to use the following command: php artisan config: cache